# Upload files asynchronously (AJAX) with HTTP/1.1 PUT method, why not?

Tags: ajax, file-upload, asynchronous, upload, asyncfileupload

Uploading files via PUT method, even binary or text, via a "normal web browser" is possible.
Why many people are just saying, that is not possible ?

Sample code with jQuery and PHP.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#uploadbutton").click(function() {
        var filename = $("#file").val();
        $.ajax({ 
        type: "PUT",
        url: "addFile.do",
           enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
           data: {file: filename},
          success: function(){
               alert( "Data Uploaded: ");
            }
        });     
    });
});
```

On the server side just read the STDIN stream like

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your solution specifically, mainly because the `PUT` method (verb) is not supported by all browsers, especially older ones, so this solution won't work for everyone.

[The topic has come up previously as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers), though not exactly the same, some answers are examples of where `PUT` and `DELETE` don't work.

[The documentation for `$.ajax()` mentions this as well](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **type**
>   Default: 'GET'
>   The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET".
>
> *Note:* Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
{file: filename}
```

When you upload a file, you have to upload the file. Telling the server what the local filename is… isn't enough.

JavaScript, running in a web browser in a standard security context, doesn't have access to read the data in the file from the user's hard disk.

Since you can't get the data, you can't upload it.

Comment: I think you missed the `PUT` HTTP Verb here, it *does* work, but it's just not as widely supported as you'd need to go this route.

Comment: Isn't that just a *second* hurdle to the problem?

Comment: Nope, that's how `PUT` works, to be 100% correct it should be:  `addFile.do/filename`, but the problem is support mainly...though yes his current implementation wouldn't work outside of PHP, at least not on any framework I can think of until the URL is corrected.  As far as the context of the question though, the problem again is lack of wide-spread support for exactly the OPs approach, rather than limitations preventing it entirely...though there are certainly a dozen good reasons *not* to do it the way the OP has anyway :)

Comment: So by specifying the PUT method, a website can persuade an XHR object to grab data from the user's hard disk and insert it into a PUT request? Does it do anything to warn the user about this first?