# Ajax File Uploads

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have the following form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload"  action="upload.php">  
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" size="10"/>
<input id="uploadbutton" type="button" value="Upload"/>  
</form>
```

The following Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uploadbutton").click(function () {
        var filename = $("#file").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "upload.php",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: {
                file: filename
            },
            success: function (text) {
                alert("Data Uploaded: " + text);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and the following PHP (as a test)

```
echo json_encode($_POST); //uses post to check as $_FILES returns nothing
```

the alert will then notify me with the response line `"file: test.jpg"` as you can see though this is a file name and not the actual file itself. How can i convert my file to get the actual file rather then the name of the file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you simply can't do it that way. you'll instead need to create a `FormData` object and send that as the data, with `processData` set to `false`. Note, since some browsers don't support the `FormData` object, those browsers can't upload files via ajax.

Comment: Is this where compatibility starts to becomes an issue?

Comment: yes. For a fully cross-browser solution (or as a fallback for browsers that don't support formData) you can submit your form to a hidden iframe.

Comment: @BenFortune that won't work as i haven't got the physical image yet, i have only got the file name

Comment: @KevinB isn't there an issue with cross compatibility and i-frames aswel though

Comment: None that would make it impossible or hard to do.

Comment: okay no problem, add this as an answer and i will accept. Thank you for your help with this. With the last comment i meant with i-frames not and i-frames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you are using is wrong for uploading files with ajax, you would need to pass a `FormData` object as the data of the request and use `processData: false`. However, some browsers don't support `FormData`, therefore you'll have to fallback to posting to a hidden iframe in those browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You still can use the "PUT" method instead of the "POST" method, it will work for all browsers except the old ones.

See  : [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849531/upload-files-asynchronously-ajax-with-http-1-1-put-method-why-not)

Comment: Lack of support is the only reason stopping me from going down this route but thank you for your input.

Comment: No problems, I've been there lately :)